# Android - setAcceptFileSchemeCookies - Where is insecurity?

Tags: android, cookies

" Use of cookies with file scheme URLs is potentially insecure and turned off by default. Do not use this feature unless you can be sure that no unintentional sharing of cookie data can take place. "
But why? I googled last hour about it, but didn't understand the attack vector

Firstly I through that if you, for example, browse the site https://example.com and try to open foobarscheme://example.com then all cookies might be sent to unknown application, but I'm not sure now

Answer (score 0):

`file:` URLs can reference JavaScript code. That JavaScript code could set cookies, which other `file:` JS code (even if from a different file) can access, due to them being considered the "same origin".

Comment: So, it means that I wasn't right with the sentence "Firstly I through that if you, for example, browse the site https://example.com and try to open foobarscheme://example.com then all cookies might be sent to unknown application, but I'm not sure now"?

Comment: And may you please add any examples? For example, we have http://example.com/file1.js ... and etc, because I'm not sure I understood everything correctly